# Pointer arrow operator fails when calling an object function declared in a separate namespace

Tags: c++, pointers, namespaces

I'm working on a basic framework for a game, where a vector is used to store objects. The Idea is to work through the vector, passing through once to check for event conditions, once to update the objects, and again to reset the objects for the next go around.

My problem is that I can't figure out the solution or workaround to an error which my implementation raises. The error is:

"undefined reference to 'g_objs::obj_event::obj_check_events()' "

```
    #ifndef IOSTREAM_H
    #define IOSTREAM_H
    #include<iostream>
#endif // IOSTREAM_H

#ifndef VECTOR_H
    #define VECTOR_H
    #include<vector>
#endif // VECTOR_H

#ifndef OBJECTS_H
    #define OBJECTS_H
    #include"objects.h"
#endif // OBJECTS_H

void game_check_events( std::vector<g_objs::obj_event>  &check_vector   ){

        g_objs::obj_event *p_object =   NULL;

    for( int i  =   0;  i   <   check_vector.capacity();    i++  ){

        p_object    =   &check_vector[i];

        //Here is the error: I would like to put:
        //p_object->obj_check_events();
        //But this raises an error-- one that seemingly cannot be fixed

        std::cout<<i<<"\n";


    };
};
```

I feel like the solution would be something very obvious, but it continues to escape me.

edit: Here is the "objects.h" header. As you can see, It's pretty bare bones.

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
    #define VECTOR_H
    #include<vector>
#endif // VECTOR_H

#ifndef GAME_H
    #define GAME_H
    #include"game.h"
#endif // GAME_H

namespace g_objs{

class obj_event{

    obj_event();

public:

    void obj_check_events();

    void obj_perform_events();

    void obj_set_events();

private:



};

class object_physics{

public:

    void obj_update_physics();

private:
};

};//end of namespace
```

Comment: "g_objs::obj_event" where is this defined ? If it is in "objects.h", can you paste that code as well ?

Comment: OK, with the new edit, I am assuming that you have 'objects.cpp' file as well for the implementation. Do you compile that as well. May be you are not including that unit?

Comment: No actually, no implementation for any of these functions has been specified. I was trying to program this sequentially, top-down, specifying the flow of the program before I added actual guts to it. But this brings up another interesting question: What's the usage of .cpp and .h files? I've just had one main.cc file and a bunch of headers, and if that's a problem, we may have found my error right there.

Comment: In case you are just testing, provide Null implementation to these functions. This can be done by putting extra '{}' in front of your function declaration as all of them return void. For eg 'void obj_check_events(){}; '

Comment: @Durendal the usage of a header file (.h) is to put declarations in, the usage of a .cpp/.cc file is to put definitions in. `obj_check_events` is declared in objects.h, but I don't see a definition. Where and in which order you define the functions does not matter. Empty inline definitions in the header as Arunmu suggest above is fine too.

Comment: .h files _usually_ provides the skeleton of the class or can be used to include other common header files or function declarations and many other puposes. *.cc/*.cpp files usually provides the implementation for those skeletons by including corresponding header file

Comment: Yup, that fixes my problem. Dang... See, it's little things like that that are what make C++ so frustrating; So thanks a ton, you saved me a crapload of time.
( For Posterity, The addition of curly braces, the 'Null Implementation' is what solved the problem )